# EPPLUS mimetype causing mcaffee site advisor warning

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, excel, epplus

I have an app which saves CSV and my action simply returns a File response. This works perfectly.

```
public ActionResult GetUserCSV(string returnUrl)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    var users = context.Users.ToList();
    sb.AppendLine("Username,Firstname,Lastname");

     foreach (var u in users)
     {
          sb.AppendLine(String.Format("{0},{1},{2}", u.username, u.firstname, u.lastname));
     }

      string csv = sb.ToString();
      var data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(csv);
      string filename = "users.csv";
      return File(data, "text/csv", filename);
}
```

I really wanted to save as xslx and I recently found EPPLUS and this tutorial
[here](http://slodge.blogspot.co.uk/2012/09/downloading-dynamic-excel-files-from.html) which uses a similar approach.

I have copied the tutorial exactly as a test in to my MVC app. It creates the excel file perfectly, however my Mcafee site advisor keeps telling me that the download is dangerous. I have changed the data to data in my db and it is still giving me the same warning.

Am I missing something, or does EPPlus create excel files with inappropriate content?

I wondered if it was the mimetype but I checked and this does appear to be correct.

Has anyone ever experienced this

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall McAfee and use a better AV.